# Continuous integration with jenkins using android studio

Tags: android, git, jenkins, android-studio, continuous-integration

I am new here to develop android application with android studio.
I created sample basic application, from this i got the project structure of the application with build.gradle files in each module(which is different from eclipse).

Then I successfully commit the code and push the entire project code to git repository by using Version Control System (VCS) in it.

I need to configure my project with jenkins server for continuous integration.

Can any one give me the step by step procedure, how to configure android studio project code (which is commited in git repository) with jenkins server.

So far i didn't find any clear procedure to configure android studio code with jenkins server for continuous integration.

Thanks in adavance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately for you, this isn't a "Tutorial" site. If you have a specific issue, people will help you. But for a tutorial, [**google around some blogs**](http://bit.ly/1GoSjrt).

Based on your description, you need to:

- Configure some triggers (prolly SCM change, or timer based)
- Perform [**GIT**](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin) checkout
- Perform [**Gradle**](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Gradle+Plugin) build step
- Decide where to Archive your artifacts

Do that, and when you have a specific issue, then ask a specific question

Comment: Can you please guide me to do set-up of the Jenkin Server for  android application like creation of the apk and unit testing perform there. I just want to do setup on my remote server.Please help me on it Thanks