# How to work with Jenkins, github and android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, jenkins, github

I am new with jenkins and continuous integration so please tell me if I have any wrong concept or silly questions. As far as i have understood, its possible to integrate jenkins,github and android studio together and when something is committed from android studio to github then jenkin compiles and builds it automatically and programmer gets notified of the success/fail result.

I have installed Jenkins and build-ed one android project from github in jenkins. But I have done it manually as in from localhost jenkins tool i have configured jenkins with github repo and run>build.

Now am looking for how to automate the process from android studio but can't find any good links/tutorials. How do I integrate the following 3 and make the process automated:

1. Jenkins
2. github
3. android studio

It might seem like a duplicate question but I couldn't really find a proper answers as below are some links I have found with no solutions:

1. [android-studio-with-jenkins-integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34853578/android-studio-with-jenkins-integration).
2. [Continuous integration with jenkins using android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27458830/continuous-integration-with-jenkins-using-android-studio)

How do I do it. Any links for how to do it would be great.

Comment: requesting off-site resources is being considered off-topic, which includes requests for tutorials & libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you push code from Android Studio to Github - and then, Jenkins can check out from there and build.

there isn't much to tell about it; except that Android Studio & Jenkins both need to act as Git clients.

Android Studio -- pushes commits --> GitHub.

Jenkins <-- pulls commits -- GitHub.

Comment: thanks but how does android studio gets success/fail notification automatically? also, does jenkin pull commits automatically and run builds?

Comment: @RashedulHasan Android Studio does not get any notification from Jenkins; this might be a misconception, which assumes Android Studio would be always running (which it doesn't) or have any notification interface (which it doesn't) - and Jenkins needs to be setup to do that; it can even run automated tests - or send notifications via mail or other means.

Comment: thanks Martin for the help. In a tutorial i found that jenkins can pull whenever any developer commits in github repo and run build. If there is any error in any commit then developers know which commit causes the error and they can fix it. I have to work on it and if I face any problem then I might ask you for help again :-)